# Python. Матрицы и двухмерные массивы

Tags: python, массивы, матрицы

Всем привет, с праздниками. Пишу с такой проблемой: не до конца понимаю работу циклов с матрицами. Нашёл туториал на паскале по схожему заданию, пробую вот как-то перевести на Python, но пока не очень получается, вот что сделал и вроде логически понимаю задачу, но не могу реализовать на коде. Пока такое есть. Сама задача:
-Есть матрица NxN и число К. Столбец с минимальным по модулю элементом в k-той строке переставить с k-тым столбцом. Мой код:

```
import random
n = int(input("Розряд: "))
matrix = [[random.randrange(-10,10) for y in range(n)] for x in range(n)]
print("Начальная матрица: ",matrix)
k = int(input("Число К:" ))
tmp = []
maxcol = 0
max = 1
#номер макс. по модулю элемента k строки и его номер (столбец)
for i in range(n):
    if max < abs(matrix[k, i]):
        max = abs(matrix[k, i])
        maxcol = 1
#переставляем столбцы
for i in range(n):
    tmp = matrix[i, k]
    matrix[i, k] = matr[i, maxcol]
    matrix[i, maxcol] = tmp
#вывод матрицы
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        print...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я точно не понял, что вам нужно, но заметил пару ошибок в коде:

1. Обращаться к элементу матрицы нужно вот так:

   ```
   matrix[строка][столбец]
   ```
2. Если вам нужно найти минимальный элемент, то переменной `max` нужно присвоить максимальное значение + 1. Я так понимаю максимальное значение элемента в матрице у вас будет 10.

   Значит присваиваем `max = 11`
3. В первом цикле вы проверяете `max < abs(matrix[k, i])`, то есть если элемент матрицы больше, то вы делаете какие либо действия, а вам нужно найти минимальный элемент.

   По этому пишем:

   ```
   if abs(matrix[k][i]) < max:
   ```

   Ну а сам цикл просто проходится по элементом `k`-ой строки, тут я думаю все понятно.
4. Далее у вас изначально `tmp` это пустой массив, я думаю раз `tmp` используется для перестановки, то это должно быть число, то есть `tmp = 0`.

   И во втором цикле у вас опечатка не `matr` а `matrix` должно быть.
5. Ну и вот пример вывода матрицы:

   ```
   for i in range(n):
       for j in range(n):
           print(matrix[i][j], end = ' ')
       print()
   ```

Полный код:

```
import random
n = int(input("Разряд: "))
matrix = [[random.randrange(-10,10) for y in range(n)] for x in range(n)]
print("Начальная матрица: ",matrix)
k = int(input("Число К:" ))
tmp = 0
maxcol = 0
max = 11
#номер макс. по модулю элемента k строки и его номер (столбец)
for i in range(n):
    if abs(matrix[k][i]) < max:
        max = abs(matrix[k][i])
        maxcol = i
#переставляем столбец
for i in range(n):
    tmp = matrix[i][k]
    matrix[i][k] = matrix[i][maxcol]
    matrix[i][maxcol] = tmp
#вывод матрицы
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        print(matrix[i][j], end = ' ')
    print()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import random
n = int(input("Розряд: "))
matrix = [[random.randrange(-10,10) for y in range(n)] for x in range(n)]
print("Начальная матрица: ",matrix)
k = int(input("Число К:" ))
abs_min=11
k_j=-1

for j in range(n):
    if abs_min>abs(matrix[k][j]):
        abs_min=abs(matrix[k][j])
        k_j=j
for i in range(n):
    matrix[i][k],matrix[i][k_j]=matrix[i][k_j], matrix[i][k]

print("Результирующая  матрица: ",matrix)
```

Результат:

```
Розряд: 5
Начальная матрица:        [[-5, -7, -5, 1, -1], 
                           [-4, 9, -2, -1, -7], 
                           [2, -8, -4, -2, -3], 
                           [-1, 9, 1, -8, 1], 
                           [-7, -1, 9, 2, -2]]

Число К:1
Результирующая  матрица:  [[-5, 1, -5, -7, -1], 
                           [-4, -1, -2, 9, -7], 
                           [2, -2, -4, -8, -3], 
                           [-1, -8, 1, 9, 1], 
                           [-7, 2, 9, -1, -2]]
```

Минимальный по абсолютному значению элемент в строке с индексом 1 - "-1" находится в столбце с индексом 3, который в итоге переставляется со столбцом с индексом 1. Как просили.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое, а если кратко, можно узнать что даёт нам "abs_min=11", если например нужно будет нам сделать с максимальным значением по модулю, тогда как модифицировать эту переменную?

Comment: @Maksey  abs_min в начале должен задаваться на единицу большим, чем второй параметр в вашей функции  random.randrange(). Вопрос "про что-то сделать  с максимальным значением по модулю" -  не понял. И да, на всякий случай https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Спасибо больше ещё раз за ответы и за руководство, думаю сумею разобраться, ибо только недавно на форуме) Хороших Вам праздников!

Comment: @Maksey даже обидно стало как-то. Автор ответа изначально сам присвоил `abs_min = 1`. А у меня сразу все расписано :( ну ладно ваше дело

Comment: @Maksey вам написал @passant, что `abs_min` это второй парамтр в функции `random.randrange()` это не совсем так. У вас задача про минимальный элемент по модулю, значит надо брать максимальный элемент **по модулю** + 1. То есть например если отрезов был бы от `-11` до `10` то `abs_min` должен равняться не 11, а 12. То есть уже по первому аргументу :)